# What is the analogue for yii app in nestjs?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

In yii, I can set global params in app module.

```
Yii::$app->language = 'en';
```

What is the analogue in nestjs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the general NodeJS approach, and Nest.js is a framework, and all things which working in Node.js should work also in Nest.js

For example:

```
global.example = 'example value';

console.log(example);
```

Comment: global for current request or its for all application ?

Comment: global is for whole application